# Import csv data into mysql table from Docker (Bash support)

Tags: mysql, bash, docker

I have a shell script which orchestrates some commands to load a csv into Mysql in Docker.

The `data.csv` i copy it over to the container along with the shell script `run_mysql.sh`.
Later i do `CMD [ "./run_mysql.sh" ]` in the Docker to run the shell.

The shell script looks like this.

```sh
# Allow  query from outside
sed -i '31 s/bind-address/#bind-address/' /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

# start service
sudo service mysql start

# run the sql script to create the table
mysql -u root < create_tables.sql 

# Following is required to load csv into the table
mysql --local-infile=1 -u root -p1

SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;
use ship_history;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE ship_movements FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;
while [ true ]; do sleep 60; done
```

In Docker however commands like `SET, USE, LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` does not run, since these are not Bash commands and i have to manually go into the container and run these to load the csv.

Is there a way i can use bash commands to load csv into the table in a Container without having to do `Docker exec -it /bin/bash` and load it manually ?

Also tried this `mysqlimport --columns='head -n 1 data.csv' --ignore-lines=1 dbname ship_movements` but doesnt recognise the dbname.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'd suggest putting the `create_tables.sql` script and the loader script into the database container's `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory before the first time you start it, or running these two tasks from outside Docker entirely (pointing a local `mysql` client at the database's published ports).  You shouldn't need `docker exec`, the `service` command, or the do-nothing loop at the end of the script for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting those errors because you need to run those commands within mysql and not in bash.

```
mysql -u mysqlUser -p -e 'your query here'
```

Maybe you could try doing something like this but adapting it to your command

Comment: Yes almost. `mysql -u root  -e 'use ship_history; select * from ship_movements;'` works, but not this. `mysql -u root -e 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE ship_movements FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;'`

Comment: `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'data.csv INTO TABLE ship_movements FIELDS TERMINATED BY , LINES TERMINATED BY n ' at line 1`

Comment: I think the problems are those ' on the filename. Try to escape them or use "

Comment: Yes that is true. But now it doesnt find the access for it strange. `ERROR 2068 (HY000) at line 1: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.` Inside mysql it works.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is with this mysql command which runs in Docker. This way you can orchestrate csv imports into mysql.

```sh
mysql -u root --local_infile=1 -e "use databasename" -e "
      LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file'
      INTO TABLE table_name 
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
      OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
      LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
      IGNORE 1 LINES 
      (COL1, COL2);"
```

Answer (score -1):

for example

CREATE TABLE `product` (
`id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`price` double(5,2) NOT NULL
)

container id 7123ea69ff42 and check your mysql container secure-file-priv is/home/

docker cp /path/to/product.txt 7123ea69ff42:/home/product.txt

mysql --local-infile=1 -uroot -p

LOAD DATA INFILE "/home/product.txt"
IGNORE
INTO TABLE product
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

Answer (score -2):

what'is error log？ please check error message

Comment: ./run_mysql.sh: line 16: SET: command not found
./run_mysql.sh: line 17: use: command not found
./run_mysql.sh: line 18: LOAD: command not found

Comment: @der_radler    you need login  mysql then use set and load     and check your secure-file-priv , your script have error

Comment: That is exactly the question. `Set` and `Load` are not bash commands.